# Checking user idle in PyQt by examining mouse clicks on the GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to implement a feature such that if the user havn't interact with the GUI for some time X, I will stop some functionality of the GUI.

Currently I have a time stamp set up so that if any of the button is not clicked in X seconds, the GUI will terminate some functionality

```
button1.triggered.connect(keep_alive)
button2.triggered.connect(keep_alive)
....
buttonN.triggered.connect(keep_alive)
```

As you can see, this is not really elegant, and doesn't scale as the button increases. Therefore I am currently investigating another method such that I monitor the mouse clicks

```
mouse = app.mouseButtons()

if mouse != Qtcore.Qt.NoButton:
    #keep_alive
```

I think this is a little hacky, but it will work for the functionality I envisioned, however, I do not know how to insert this to the execution loop of the QT.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: It would be better if a timer triggered the enable/disable behaviour on the frame the widgets (buttons, etc.) exist on. That will solve the scaling issue.

Comment: Thanks, does Qt frame register mouse clicks?

Comment: I think how it works is; you `connect` a click handler to both the frame and its widgets. When the click event is triggered, you pass the event from the widget to the frame (I think by calling `event.Skip()`, you'll need to check this).

Comment: Cool, so I imagine I would group all the button in a handler, and somehow connect the handler to the frame? And do `groups_of_button.triggered.connect(keep_alive)` ?

Comment: I would suggest your original solution is fine, and if it doesn't scale well to N buttons, you probably want to rethink how you create those N buttons (as in, make them in a loop, store them in an iterable datastructure so you can loop over them and connect them to your keepalive method, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You must intercept the mouse events by reimplementing the `mousePressEvent`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent

To make sure that it won't affect your other functionalities you'll need to propagate it to the parent widget. Read more details: https://www.qt.io/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation

I would proceed by implementing it in the main window and make sure all mouse events are propagated to it.